# How to list all admin of a specific role

Tags: admin, role

How can I retrieve the list of all admin that has the same role?

For example, I create a new role called "Seller" and assign some admin users to that role.

How to list all admin users with the role "Seller"?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get all the Roles

```
   $roles = Mage::getModel('admin/roles')->getCollection();
   foreach($roles as $role):
      echo '<br/>Role : '.$role->getId()." | ".$role->getRoleName();
   endforeach;
```

To get the Role users

```
  $roles_users = Mage::getResourceModel('admin/roles_user_collection');
  foreach($roles_users as $roleuser):
   $user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($roleuser->getUserId());
   echo '<br/>User : '.$user->getUsername()." | ".$user->getFirstname();
  endforeach;
```

Or in your database you can check in the table `admin_role` which role you want to check, for example id=1 is my administrator and then with the query

```
select * from admin_role where parent_id='1'
```

You get all users with the Administrator role.
And I have customer service with id=2 so the query would be

```
select * from admin_role where parent_id='2'
```

Which gives me all users with the role customer service and so on...

Comment: I´ve updated it for specific roles in mysql

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to get all the admin users belonging to a specific admin role. On the one hand, you can build the collection of admin users by first retrieving the user IDs belonging to the admin role and then loading a new Mage_Admin_Model_Role object per user ID:

```
$adminUserCollection = array();
$adminUserIds = Mage::getModel('admin/roles')
    ->load("Sellers", 'role_name')
    ->getRoleUsers();
foreach($adminUserIds as $userId) {
    $adminUser = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($adminUserId);
    $adminUserCollection[] = $adminUser;
}
```

Secondly, you can load the collection as follows:

```
$adminRoleId = Mage::getModel('admin/role')->load('Sellers', 'role_name')->getId();
$adminUserCollection = Mage::getModel('admin/role')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', ['eq'=>$adminRoleId])
    ->join(['user' => 'admin/user'], user.user_id=main_table.user_id');
```

I am not sure which method is faster, but IMO the second option is slightly more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Use below mysql query

```
select admin_user.user_id,firstname,lastname,email,authorization_role.parent_id as pid,(select role_name from authorization_role where role_id = pid) as admin_rule_name,(select   GROUP_CONCAT( resource_id SEPARATOR "||") from authorization_rule where permission = 'allow' and role_id = pid )  from admin_user left join authorization_role On admin_user.user_id = authorization_role.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

select admin_user.user_id,firstname,lastname,email,authorization_role.parent_id as pid,(select role_name from authorization_role where role_id = pid) as admin_rule_name,(select   GROUP_CONCAT( resource_id SEPARATOR "||") from authorization_rule where permission = 'allow' and role_id = pid )  from admin_user

left join authorization_role On admin_user.user_id = authorization_role.user_id